# Excel VBA Debug: Loop not searching through the whole range

Tags: vba, loops, excel, copy-paste

I wrote a basic macro to search through a range (in one sheet) and then copy the selected cell (to another sheet) based on a 3rd sheet holding the selection values. I've used the loop as for i = x to y bu it looks like the macro is skipping some rows !???!
i.e. If there are 4 valid values to be copied on rows 1 to 4, the macro only copies values from rows 2 and 4 (ditching the valid cells 1 and 3). Here's the code:

```
Sub XXXXX()
Dim i As Integer
Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet: Set PasteSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim CopySheet As Worksheet: Set CopySheet = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim SearchSheet As Worksheet: Set SearchSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim LookupID, LookupID_SearchRange, CopyValueID, CopyValueID_Paste As Range

For i = 7 To 2000 'I've also used the (Step 1) option with no success
RowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(PasteSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1 'finds the last cell to be used for copy

Set LookupID = CopySheet.Range("A" & i) 'searches all values within column A from row 7 to 2000
Set LookupID_SearchRange = SearchSheet.Range("A:A") ' Seaches if the values from Sheet3 are present in Sheet 1
Set CopyValueID = CopySheet.Range("X" & i) 'counter that follows the same search on A but selects values on X
Set CopyValueID_Paste = PasteSheet.Range("A" & RowCount) 'When it finds the ID, it copies some cell to the last row in Sheet2
      ' Initially  there was an additional RowCount (+1) for CopyValueID. Corrected based on answers for future refrence of the cleaned code.
If Not IsError(Application.Match(LookupID, LookupID_SearchRange, 0)) Then
    If CopyValueID.Value <> "" Then
        CopyValueID.Copy
        CopyValueID_Paste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Why does the code selects and copies values from rows 2 and 4 (it seams like it's using a +1 step?)
Thanks.

Comment: One quick thing you may want to fix is the sixth Dim line.  If you Dim with a comma separated list, each item needs its own `As` or it is implicitly dimensioned as a Variant.  In that sixth line, `LookupID, LookupID_SearchRange, CopyValueID` are all implicitly dimmed as Variants, while only `CopyValueID_Paste As Range` explicitly declares `CopyValueID_Paste` to be a Range.  The corrected line would read `Dim LookupID As Range, LookupID_SearchRange As Range, CopyValueID As Range, CopyValueID_Paste As Range`.  Unfortunately, I don't believe this fix will solve the issue you have encountered.

Comment: Are there any blank lines PasteSheet!A:A? If there are I don't think you'll want to be using COUNTA. Try http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Comment: @Blackhawk 10x for the tip, I hadn't that in mind when writing the question. I've translated my code to general description for disclosure of the original code. I usually declare a dim and set it immediately with: on the same line :)

Comment: @NickSlash no, there are no blanks, so the CountA does it's job in this case. The issue above is related to reading the date, more than finding the space to paste it. 10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining `RowCount` as `CountA + 1`:

```
RowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(PasteSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1 'finds the last cell to be used for copy
```

then you actually add one again in the row you are pasting:

```
Set CopyValueID_Paste = PasteSheet.Range("A" & RowCount + 1) ' When it finds the ID, it copies some cell to the last row in Sheet2
```

I think you are therefore overwriting your results? Removing one of the `+1`'s should do the trick.

Editorial: Happy to see someone defining the ranges they copy to and from, rather than using a bunch of `Select`'s... definitely better coding style!

Comment: +1 for the Editorial. Totally agree on defining the ranges cleanly - so many people use a jumbled mess of selects.

Comment: 10x for the feedback. will amend this 1st thing tomorrow. Hope it does the job and this is the true issue as the doubled +1 might be a "typo" inserted during the rewriting of the code (for disclosure). Keep you posted.

Comment: It's always better to have more than one pair of eyes looking over the code. While analyzing it, today it was obvious, yesterday was then most elusive bug. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're adding a `+1` to the RowCount in two places.

```
...
RowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(PasteSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1
...
Set CopyValueID_Paste = PasteSheet.Range("A" & RowCount + 1) '<-- Remove the +1 here
```

A few other notes - nice code overall --------------------------

- As pointed out in the comments, there is a pretty agreed upon best practice to find the RowCount: `RowCount = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. This will solve the problem of possible blank cells in the column, which would throw off the COUNTA.
- You can do this without COPY and PASTE with `CopyValueID_PASTE.value = CopyValueID.Value`.  It will make a huge efficiency difference if you are doing this over a lot of rows.

Comment: It looks like the doubled +1 slipped my checks. 10x in my current setup My ranges are relatively small (20 x 1500) so performance is not an issue. Still will give it a try!