# Excel 2010 VBA: Copy a row to a new sheet based on value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

As stated in the Title, I am trying to first check the value in a particular cell, then if it matches, copy the entire row into a new sheet. No Errors are thrown but the result is empty.
Please assist.

```
Public Function freshSheet(inPart As String)
    Dim mag As Worksheet
    Dim currRow As Long
    Dim iohd As Worksheet
    Dim magCount As Integer

    Set iohd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("IOHD")
    'TODO: Create Magic Sheet.
    Set mag =   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    mag.Name = "Magic"

    'TODO: Iterate through IOHD Sheet.
    For currRow = iohd.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        'TODO: IS PART EQUAL TO INPART? IF SO, COPY TO MAGIC SHEET
        If iohd.Cells(currRow, 2).Value = inPart Then
            magCount = mag.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            iohd.Cells(currRow, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=mag.Cells(magCount, 1)
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Hello there, Robert. First, usage of `Active` in `Workbook`,`Sheet`, or `Cell` has more disadvantages than advantages. Second, to get the last row of a sheet, `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is the ideal method. Please see my modification of your code below. :) Also, declaring `magCount` as `Long` is much better in the long run.

Comment: Why not use [AUTOFILTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)?

Comment: Because the sheet (IOHD) is already being filtered. I would need to reset those filters every time I wanted to do this.
I will look into your advice BK. Thanks.

Comment: may want to see this also as it covers the same method. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815763/excel-vba-debug-loop-not-searching-through-the-whole-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I tried the above method and found it was much easier to simply clear the filters and reapply them.
Personally, I do not really like that idea because I find the idea of removing something only to add it again; however, in code its much simpler.

Credit goes to: Siddharth Rout

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Public Function freshSheet(inPart As String)
    Dim mag As Worksheet
    Dim currRow As Long
    Dim iohd As Worksheet
    Dim magCount As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set iohd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IOHD")
    'TODO: Create Magic Sheet.
    Set mag =   ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    mag.Name = "Magic"
    lRow = iohd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For currRow = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If iohd.Cells(currRow, 2).Value = inPart Then
            magCount = mag.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            iohd.Cells(currRow, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=mag.Cells(magCount, 1)
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Let us know if this helps. :)

Comment: Will try this out tomorrow. Out of the office today. Thank you for the input!